# Why the tail block has been lost when encrypt by AesCryptoServiceProvider in .Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, encryption, cryptography

I tried to use AesCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt data, passing by Byte Array.

Run this code, you'll see the the default data length is 32*8bit which is just I set, it runs perfectly.

And then, you can set the length to any other you want. For example, 33, which means the total length of the data (33*8bit) is not an integer multiple of 128bit.

So before AES, it needs being padded to 48*8bit.

However, **.Net discarded the the last incomplete block**. And I think this is why I met an exception when decrypting.

Well, is there anything wrong when I deal with AesCryptoServiceProvider class?
Or that's a problem need to avoid?
What should I do to fix this and use AES to encrypt data?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Module Module1
    Private intKeySize As Integer = 256
    Private Const c_intBlockSize As Integer = 128   'AES ONLY use 128bit block
    Private pdmPaddingMode As PaddingMode = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    Private cpmCipherMode As CipherMode = CipherMode.CFB
    Private Const c_strDefault As String = "D49303DCDF5AAE2B128001EA48D19D04"

    Sub Main()

        prpPaddingMode = PaddingMode.ANSIX923 'you can set differen padding to test
        Dim setlength As Integer = 32
tgA:
        Dim objRandom As New System.Random(Now.Millisecond)
        Dim inp(setlength - 1) As Byte
        For i As Integer = 0 To inp.GetUpperBound(0) 'Random data generated as test data
            inp(i) = CByte(objRandom.Next(0, 255))
        Next i
        BytesShow(inp, "Input")

        Dim outp() As Byte = EncryptString_Aes(inp, NewKey(c_strDefault), Hex2Byte(c_strDefault)) 'I use c_strDefault as the IV and Key
        BytesShow(outp, "Encrypted")

        'The two lines below meet an exception probably becuase the final block lost in encryption
        'Dim dep() As Byte = DecryptString_Aes(outp, NewKey(c_strDefault), Hex2Byte(c_strDefault))
        'BytesShow(dep, "Decrypted")
        Console.WriteLine("===========" & vbCrLf & "Finished, please press any key to continue:")
        Console.ReadKey()
        Console.WriteLine("===========" & vbCrLf & "===========" & vbCrLf & "What's Next Test Data Length?")
        setlength = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        GoTo tgA
    End Sub

    Public Function EncryptString_Aes(ByVal plainByte() As Byte, ByVal Key() As Byte, ByVal IV() As Byte) As Byte()
        Dim encrypted As Byte()
        Using aesAlg As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
            aesAlg.Mode = prpCipherMode
            aesAlg.Padding = prpPaddingMode
            aesAlg.BlockSize = prpBlockSize
            aesAlg.Key = Key
            If aesAlg.Mode <> CipherMode.ECB Then
                aesAlg.IV = IV
            End If
            Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)
            Dim msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
            Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                'Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt, Encoding.UTF8)
                '    swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
                'End Using
                Debug.WriteLine(aesAlg.Mode.ToString)
                Debug.WriteLine(aesAlg.Padding.ToString)
                csEncrypt.Write(plainByte, 0, plainByte.Length)
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
        Return encrypted
    End Function
    Public Function DecryptString_Aes(ByVal cipherByte() As Byte, ByVal Key() As Byte, ByVal IV() As Byte) As Byte()
        Dim msOut As New MemoryStream()
        Using aesAlg As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
            aesAlg.Mode = prpCipherMode
            aesAlg.Padding = prpPaddingMode
            aesAlg.BlockSize = prpBlockSize
            aesAlg.Key = Key
            If aesAlg.Mode <> CipherMode.ECB Then
                aesAlg.IV = IV
            End If
            Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)
            Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(cipherByte)
                Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                    'Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt, Encoding.UTF8)
                    '    decrypted = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
                    'End Using
                    Debug.WriteLine(aesAlg.Mode.ToString)
                    Debug.WriteLine(aesAlg.Padding.ToString)
                    Dim bytBuffer(1023) As Byte
                    Dim intCount As Integer
                    Do
                        intCount = csDecrypt.Read(bytBuffer, 0, bytBuffer.Length)
                        msOut.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intCount)
                        Debug.WriteLine("intCount = " & intCount.ToString)
                    Loop While intCount > 0
                End Using
            End Using
            'Dim msDecrypt As New MemoryStream()
            'Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            '    'Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csDecrypt, Encoding.UTF8)
            '    '    swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
            '    'End Using
            '    csEncrypt.Write(cipherByte, 0, cipherByte.Length)
            '    decrypted = msDecrypt.ToArray()
            'End Using
        End Using
        Return msOut.ToArray()
    End Function
    Public Sub BytesShow(ByRef bytin() As Byte)
        BytesShow(bytin, "ByteArray_Show_End")
    End Sub
    Public Sub BytesShow(ByRef bytin() As Byte, ByRef msg As String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To bytin.GetUpperBound(0) '测试用的数据用随机数值
            Select Case (i Mod 16)
                Case 0
                    Console.Write(i.ToString.PadLeft(5) & "#) " & bytin(i).ToString("x2"))
                Case 15
                    Console.WriteLine(" " & bytin(i).ToString("x2"))
                Case Else
                    Console.Write(" " & bytin(i).ToString("x2"))
            End Select
        Next i
        Console.WriteLine("  (#Total: " & (bytin.GetUpperBound(0) + 1).ToString & "#)" & vbCrLf & "===================" & msg)
    End Sub
    Public Function getSha512HashBytes(ByVal strInput As String) As Byte()
        Dim bytData As Byte()
        Using Sha512Hasher As New SHA512CryptoServiceProvider
            bytData = Sha512Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInput))
        End Using
        Return bytData
    End Function
    Public Function NewKey(ByVal StringKey As String) As Byte()
        Dim objRfc2898 As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(StringKey, getSha512HashBytes(StringKey), 1000)
        Dim bytKey As Byte() = objRfc2898.GetBytes(CInt(prpKeySize / 8))
        objRfc2898.Reset()
        objRfc2898.Dispose()
        Return bytKey
    End Function
    Public Function Hex2Byte(ByVal StringValue As String) As Byte()
        Dim bytValue((StringValue.Length \ 2) - 1) As Byte
        For i As Integer = 0 To ((StringValue.Length \ 2) - 1)
            bytValue(i) = CByte("&H" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(StringValue, ((i * 2) + 1), 2))
        Next i
        Return bytValue
    End Function
    Friend Property prpKeySize() As Integer
        Get
            Return intKeySize
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Select Case value
                Case 128, 192, 256
                    intKeySize = value
                Case Else
                    Throw New CryptographicException("The key size is not one of the KeySize values.")
            End Select
        End Set
    End Property
    Friend ReadOnly Property prpBlockSize As Integer
        Get
            Return c_intBlockSize
        End Get
    End Property
    Friend Property prpPaddingMode As PaddingMode
        Get
            Return pdmPaddingMode
        End Get
        Set(value As PaddingMode)
            Select Case value
                Case PaddingMode.ANSIX923, PaddingMode.ISO10126, PaddingMode.PKCS7, PaddingMode.Zeros, PaddingMode.None
                    pdmPaddingMode = value
                Case Else
                    Throw New CryptographicException("The padding mode is not one of the supported PaddingMode values.")
            End Select
        End Set
    End Property
    Friend Property prpCipherMode As CipherMode
        Get
            Return cpmCipherMode
        End Get
        Set(value As CipherMode)
            Select Case value
                Case CipherMode.CBC, CipherMode.CFB, CipherMode.ECB
                    cpmCipherMode = value
                Case Else
                    Throw New CryptographicException("The cipher mode is not one of the supported CipherMode values.")
            End Select
        End Set
    End Property
End Module
```

Anyway, thank all of you for taking time reading this and helping me solve the problem. Sincerely.

Comment: msEncrypt.ToArray() is executed too soon, before the memory stream is completely written.  It needs to go *after* the Using statement.  Or you need to use csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock() explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found out.

After write data into csEncrypt (the CryptoStream class),

```
    csEncrypt.Write(plainByte, 0, plainByte.Length)
```

We should **close the stream**, which let .Net know that "That's all, you've got all the data."

```
    csEncrypt.Close()
```

And then, the last incomplete block get padded and encrypted. At this time, we can read the result.

```
    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
```

So, the total code is like this:

```
    csEncrypt.Write(plainByte, 0, plainByte.Length)
    csEncrypt.Close()
    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
```